# How to use proxy in Selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium

In the documentation, I read that for using proxy set while building driver like this:

```
var driver = new webdriver.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
    .setProxy(proxy.manual({http: 'host:1234'}))
    .build();
```

When I use this code with proxy '103.87.16.2:80' - .setProxy(proxy.manual({http: 'host:1234'})), I still have my home IP.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set chrome to a proxy in code.  It's in the Webdriver Advanced documentation.

**Chrome**

Is basically the same as internet explorer. It uses the same configuration on the machine as IE does (on windows). On Mac it uses the System Preference -> Network settings. On Linux it uses (on Ubuntu) System > Preferences > Network Proxy Preferences (Alternatively in “/etc/environment” set http_proxy). **As of this writing it is unknown how to set the proxy programmatically.**

https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp